# Is there a way to display a "template" in Python's input() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, command-line-interface

Just to clarify, by "template" I don't mean the prompt which you get by passing a string to the function. Instead, I wanted to have a preset string displayed and the user to fill in the blanks in said string. For example: `input("Date of birth: ", template="%/%/%")`, with `%` being where the user would type, without modifying the `/`s. To the user, it would look like: `>Date of birth: _/ /` , with the underscore being the user's cursor. And then, as the user types, it would skip the `/` and go to the next `%` (which is just a blank space to the user). Finally, when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `input()` would only return what the user typed, and not the rest of the template.

Now, I don't need something with that exact syntax and behavior, I really just need a way to make the user type and replace parts of a premade string. Is that even possible? The closest thing I could find looking around the internet and Stack Overflow itself was placeholders for the input, which is almost what I need, but not quite, since the entire placeholder gets deleted when the user types.

Comment: No, `input` is not meant to provide a high-level interface to the user. It's a simple wrapper that can display a prompt and call `sys.stdin.readline`, then strip the trailing newline from the result (and raising an exception instead of returning an empty string to indicate no input was read).

Comment: Something tells me it might be possible to do something via [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) but that is just my intuition

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining that, @chepner.
I'll look into Curses, as JonSG suggested, might be just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do that in the terminal via `input()`.
**But** if you really need something like this, you might want to use the package tkinter. With that you can create a "UI" with a input field and a (as you call it) template init.

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer for a question about a `command-line-interface`.

Comment: I did answer the initial question and showed them another possible method, of getting the result they want/need. :)

Comment: Yep, it seems `input()` is not the way to go. I appreciate the suggestion (and have used tkinter before), but this project is CLI only.